# Akka Http retrieve a string value with help of Segment PathMatcher

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm trying to implement a simple API where I can get path parameter as a `String`. Here is my test code:

```
class SimpleRouteTest extends WordSpec
  with Matchers
  with ScalatestRouteTest {

  val routes: Route = pathPrefix("foo") {
    get {
      complete("GET /foo")
    } ~
    pathPrefix(Segment) { seg =>
      get {
        complete(s"GET /foo/$seg")
      }
    }
  }

  "The routes should handle" should {
    "GET /foo correctly" in {
      Get("/foo") ~> routes ~> check {
        responseAs[String] shouldBe  "GET /foo"
      }
    }
    "GET /foo/any" in {
      Get("/foo/any") ~> routes ~> check {
        responseAs[String] shouldBe  "GET /foo/any"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Unfortunately the second test fails with message:

"GET /foo[]" was not equal to "GET /foo[/any]"

Who can give a hint, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what your code tries to do:

- match the path with the prefix `/foo`
- if method is `GET`, complete with `"GET /foo"`
- **otherwise** if the remaining path starts with some segment `seg`, complete with `s"GET /foo/$seg"`

The `~` operator stops at the first operand, since all the condition are met (starts with `/foo` and is a `GET`). You might want to pass the more precise one as first operand, or specify that you want a `PathEnd` in your first case.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I missed this detail (~) while read the akka http docs :(

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted if it pleases you, so that it can help future SO users.